# Editar un valor de un atributo de una tabla en MySQL desde Netbeans usando Java

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo este proyecto, básicamente es un sistema de inventario de una dulcería, el problema es que me da un error del tipo `java.lang.NullPointerException` pero no me dice en qué líenea.

Al momento de tomar el atributo 'cantidad' de la tabla inventario y sumarle o restarle dependiendo de la operación, la tabla inventario tiene un id(PK), cantidad, id_producto(FK) y un id_estado(FK) y al momento de mostrarlo en un jFrame hago un join llamando al atributo descripción de la tabla producto a través del id del mismo; eso no es problema, el problema es guardar la nueva cantidad.

Ya probé con varias sentencias y me da el mismo error, ¿pueden ayudarme?

Adjunto el código que intento usar para sumar inventario, supongo que será parecido para restarlo.

```
    private void btningresoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // SE REALIZA EL AUMENTO DE PRODUCTOS EN STOCK

        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps;
        ResultSet rs;
        PreparedStatement ps1;
        ResultSet rs1;
        PreparedStatement ps2;
        ResultSet rs2;
        try {

            //Sentencia ps guarda id, cantidad y categoria
            //Sentencia ps1 guarda nombre llamando el nombre con el idproducto
            ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT a.id_producto,b.nombre,a.cantidad,a.id_categoria FROM tblinventario a, tblproducto b WHERE a.id_producto = ?");
            ps1 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT a.id_producto,b.nombre,a.cantidad,a.id_categoria FROM tblinventario a, tblproducto b WHERE b.idproducto = ?");
            ps.setString(1, txtbuscar.getText());
            ps1.setString(1, txtbuscar.getText());

            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            rs1 = ps1.executeQuery();
            String cantidad = txtcantidad.getText();
            int total = 0;
            int viejoStock = 0;
            int nuevoStock =0;
            nuevoStock = Integer.parseInt(cantidad);

            if (rs.next()) {
                viejoStock = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(3));
                total = viejoStock + nuevoStock;
                ps2 = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE tblinventario SET cantidad=? WHERE id_producto= ?");
                ps2.setString(1, txtcantidad.getText());
                ps2.setString(2, txtbuscar.getText());
                int res = ps2.executeUpdate();
                if (res > 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cantidad <modificada");

                } else {
                    System.out.println(res);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al Modificar Cantidad");

                }


                //Statement actualizar = con.createStatement();
                //actualizar.executeUpdate("UPDATE tblinventario SET cantidad = '"+total);
                DefaultTableModel modelo6 = new DefaultTableModel();
                modelo6.addColumn("ID Producto");
                modelo6.addColumn("Nombre del producto");
                modelo6.addColumn("Cantidad");
                modelo6.addColumn("ID Categoría");
                tabla6.setModel(modelo6);
                String data2[] = new String[4];
                data2[0] = rs.getString(1);
                data2[1] = rs1.getString(2);
                data2[2] = rs.getString(3);
                data2[3] = rs.getString(4);
                modelo6.addRow(data2);
                tabla6.setModel(modelo6);
                con.close();;

            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR AL AUMENTAR INVENTARIO");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Java te dice siempre no sólo la línea del error, sino que además te muestra una traza del mismo, o sea, las líneas de las llamadas anteriores a esa línea. Pulsa en [edit] para agregar el mensaje completo del error para poder ayudarte y además ayudarte un poco a saber leer los mensajes de error, pues te ahorrarán muchas horas de depuración. En cuanto al código, no tiene sentido que prepares dos consultas idénticas, pues una de las finalidades de las consultas preparadas es precisamente poder reutilizar la misma consulta. Tampoco es bueno mezclar en el mismo proceso ...

Comment: ... un `SELECT` junto con otra consulta cualquiera, `UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT` u otro `SELECT`. Cuando ejecutas una consulta los resultados quedan como un recurso abierto y abrir otro recurso mientras ese primero está pendiente puede provocar problemas. Aparte de eso, las tablas son relacionales y es mejor hacer uso de esa posibilidad para simplificar el trabajo. Eso quiere decir que por ejemplo puedes combinar un `SELECT` con un `UPDATE` en la misma consulta, sin tener que ejecutar consultas aparte.

Comment: Java no me mostró la línea ni qué sucedió después o antes, por eso digo que es un error muy extraño, y respecto a las dos consultas, es porque la primera me llama todos los parámetros menos el atributo 'nombre', no sé por qué, y la segunda me llama sólo el 'nombre', excepto los otros parámetros, por lo que juntando las dos consultas obtengo el resultado que quiero. Y pordías darme un ejemplo de cómo usar dos consultas seguidas?

Comment: Tienes que verificar la consola para ver el error, no la interfaz de la aplicación. En cuanto a las consultas separadas, sería cuestión de ejecutar cada una aparte y guardar los datos en variables, cerrar los recursos que cada consulta haya abierto y finalmente usar las variables. De todos modos todo lo que dices me parece extraño. Habría que investigar por qué no te devuelve el nombre en la primera consulta y normalizar el código. Esa mezcla de consultas similares no está bien.

Comment: Ya logré unificar mis consultas en una sentencia, ahora tengo otro error, quiero buscar y mostrar en un JTable todos los elementos que coincidan con mi criterio de búsqueda, y en principio funciona, pero sólo me muestra el primero que encuentra, no muestra los otros, cómo puedo arreglar eso? Intenté usar un 'for' pero da error de índice.

Comment: Sugiero que abras una nueva pregunta con ese nuevo problema, indicando el código que te está fallando y el error que está dando. Es un nuevo problema y debe ser planteado aparte, además en un comentario no podría entenderse del todo el contexto. Generalmente los resultados de una consulta se leen con un `while` que va moviendo el objeto  `ResultSet` donde están los datos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda